# Ruby: create an image with RGB values

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a series of RGB values I'm working with in Ruby, and I'd like to take those and output an image from them. I've done the processing with RMagick, but it consumes a ton of memory so I was hoping to profile that against other alternatives. Right now I'm just getting the image pixels using the ImageMagick command line `convert` option to get the pixel data, but I can't seem to figure out how to write the data back out to a new image. How do I take an array of RGB values and write them into a png or jpg image on the filesystem?

Comment: Show your RMagick code that loads the RGB to image. As you've profiled it, make sure to include the part with bad memory use. There may be a smart way to improve performance using its raw pixel data in/out options.

Comment: I'm trying to output to a png at a user specified path.

Comment: @NeilSlater There are definitely ways to improve our RMagick code, but I was hoping to be able to see the difference in performance versus a more basic approach. We started out with the most naive solution that solves our problem and are now doing some profiling and trying some different strategies to reduce the memory. I'll post up a new question if I hit a wall optimizing.

Comment: If you are writing PNG files, then chunky_png may be worth looking at: https://rubygems.org/gems/chunky_png

Comment: Yeah, I actually ended up using chunky_png to output the pixels, but it's an ugly nested loop to assign each of them. I was kind of hoping there might be a nice `convert` one liner like there is to get the pixels in the first place.